# DistinctBy not recognized as method

Tags: c#, linq

Maybe I am missing an using? (I have `using System.Linq`).

With `Distinct` no problem.

This is my command that i want to add DistinctBy:

```
 List<Capture> list = db.MyObject.Where(x => x.prop == "Name").ToList();
```

Comment: There is no built in linq method with name "DistinctBy". unless you are using some third party library

Comment: Where this method you took from? Pls link to docs

Comment: DistinctBy is the method

Comment: Ther is not extension method or native method `DistinctBy()` in Enumerable type. I have only found that this method is available in F#, but not C#.

Comment: I suspect you are trying to use the MoreLINQ `DistinctBy` extension method; you need to add the MoreLINQ package to your project (e.g. via nuget) first.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/

Comment: For reference, this is now part of Webgrease
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebGrease/1.6.0

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can add a extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TKey> property)
{
    return items.GroupBy(property).Select(x => x.First());
}
```

and You can use it like

```
 List<Capture> list = db.MyObject.Where(x => x.prop == "Name")
                     .DistinctBy(y=> y.prop )
                     .ToList();
```

OR, You can use `DistincyBy` provided through [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

Answer (score 2):

**Another example:**

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        var seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
            if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MyList.GroupBy(a=>a.item).select(a=>a.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();//use this

//is equal to 

 MyList.DistinctBy(a=>a.item).ToList();//its not work with linq
```

Answer (score 2):

Now in dotnet 6.0 there is a built in DistinctBy extension in System.Linq namespace

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0

Comment: Note: If I am not incorrect, .netstandard2.1 does not contain `DistinctBy` either. (Double negation - that is not good programming practice.)